# How to start play application inside integration test?

Tags: scala, playframework, integration-testing

Let's say I have play application

```
class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
   override def load(context: Context): Application =
    new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with AhcWSComponents { }.application
}
```

And I'm trying to run it inside integration test with some mocks to test. My current (not working) approach:

```
    lazy val app: Application = {
      val customContext = ApplicationLoader.createContext(Environment.simple(new java.io.File("."), Mode.Test))
      new AppLoader().load(customContext)
    }
    Play.start(app)
```

But http server isn't started, all my requests are rejected with `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

Is there any way to start play application without guice magic?

Comment: Something like [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/5428e7f8ed373efd7672eeeb4ea50d80bffcdea0/framework/src/play-integration-test/src/test/scala/play/it/http/BadClientHandlingSpec.scala) or maybe `OneServerPerSuite`?

Comment: @insan-e Thank you for hint, I will figure out dependencies and will compile first example. And what's the difference between this approach and `OneServerPerSuite`?

Comment: IDK, the second one is recommended in the docs, so you should probably go with `OneServerPerSuite`.. I haven't worked with the compile-time DI, so I thought you could find something useful in the Play's source code tests. :D

Comment: Yeah, but it's runtime DI. And I get `Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.` exceptions while using `OneServerPerSuite`. Guess, I need to rewrite application in this guice manner to resolve.

Comment: There is also this repo I found: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-compile-di-with-tests